# How to decode an invalid stringified JSON - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

This Stringified JSON array is invalid because the map keys and values are not in quotes but I wanna decode it:

```
"[{division: bacteriology, speciality: microbiology, tests: [appearence of urine], category: urine}]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as your string is not in proper json format, so i try to decode this particular string by converting it to proper json-

```
String data = "[{division: bacteriology, speciality: microbiology, tests: [appearence of urine], category: urine}]";
    String formattedDataInJson = data.replaceAll("{", "{\"").replaceAll("}", "\"}").replaceAll(":", "\":\"").replaceAll(",", "\",\"").replaceAll("\"\"", "\"");
    String division = jsonDecode(formattedDataInJson)[0]["division"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an online tool, you could use this [JSONFormatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#)
PFA for example screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I wanna do that in the code